# Sorting list in Python causes error

Tags: python, list

I'm having a problem sorting list in Python here's my code:

```
lista = [ 1, .89, .65, .90]

for x in lista.sort():
    print (x)
```

Error is:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 7):

The `sort` method sorts the list in-place; it always returns `None`.
What you can do:

```
lista = [ 1, .89, .65, .90]
lista.sort()

for x in lista:
    print (x)
```

Or, as @Delgan pointed out, you can use the `sorted` function, which returns the sorted list:

```
lista = [ 1, .89, .65, .90]

for x in sorted(lista):
    print (x)
```

Comment: Or use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) instead.

Answer (score 4):

[`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) only change the list but return None, you need:

```
lista = [1, .89, .65, .90]
lista.sort()

for x in lista:
    print(x)
```

Or simply use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
lista = [1, .89, .65, .90]

for x in sorted(lista):
    print (x)
```

`sorted()` return a new list but sorted, note that it doesn't change the current list.

Answer (score 3):

`.sort()` doesn't return anything.  If you want to modify the list to be sorted you can do

```
lista = [ 1, .89, .65, .90]
lista.sort()
for x in lista:
    print (x)
```

or if you want to keep the list in the original order you can use `sorted` which returns a new list of the sorted elements:

```
lista = [ 1, .89, .65, .90]

for x in sorted(lista):
    print (x)
```